# Function to timestamp when cell is updated Javascript | Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some code that I am trying to create a timestamp when statuses are put in column C. The status is updated/written by a script as well. When that status is written by script it does not automatically stamp the statuses. Is there any way to change this?

For example, if I write 'error' in the status it stamps but, if the script changes it to error it does not stamp.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  Logger.log('edited');
  if (column == 3){
    var timestamp = new Date();
    var row = range.getRow();
    var value = e.value;
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    Logger.log("edited cell: "+range.getA1Notation());
    if( value == "queued"){
      sheet.getRange(row, 8).setValue(timestamp);
    } else if(value == "delivered"){
      sheet.getRange(row, 10).setValue(timestamp);
    } else if(value == "error"){
      sheet.getRange(row, 9).setValue(timestamp);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you need to understand is onEdit does not run on every edit, especially when editing large amounts of data quickly or simultaneously so you need to code it in such a way that is assuming this will happen (even if you get your current script working)

Comment: @CodeCamper Okay, I understand, what do you think the best way to do this is? I tried doing something with some IFS statements but, it didn't work quite as I intended.

Comment: Would you recommend and onChange forumla?

Comment: I suggest to move/put the creation of timestamp into the other script that updates the sheet as well. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

According to [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started), the `onEdit(e)` & `onSelectionChange(e)` will only work when a user interacts on the sheet (e.g. user clicks or edits a cell). When a sheet is auto populated via script or formula without any user interactions, these simple triggers will not kick in.

With that being said, I recommend that you put your timestamp code on the script where you have the code that automatically add the statuses on column C instead. This way, on every status that's added on column C, a timestamp is automatically added as well.

For your reference, I've created a test Sheet here:

[image]

Then, I've created a sample test script below, where it adds `queued` to the sheet followed by the code to add the timestamp:

```
function AddStatus() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX").getSheetByName('Sheet1');//Spreadhseet ID and the Sheet name where statuses will be added on column C
ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,3).setValue('queued');//sample code where status "queued" will be added on the lastrow of column c on Sheet1 on the Spreadsheet

var range = ss.getDataRange().getValues();//it gets all statuses that were added on column C
var timestamp = new Date();
  for(var x = 1; x <= range.length; x++){//A loop to check every status on column C
      var value = ss.getRange(x,3).getValue();//gets the status value on every row
      if(value == 'queued' && ss.getRange(x, 8).getValue() == ''){//checks if the status value matches the condition and will only put timestamp if there's no existing one yet
        ss.getRange(x, 8).setValue(timestamp);//sets the timestamp
      }else if(value == 'delivered' && ss.getRange(x, 10).getValue() == ''){
        ss.getRange(x, 10).setValue(timestamp);
      }else if(value == 'error' && ss.getRange(x, 9).getValue() == ''){
        ss.getRange(x, 9).setValue(timestamp);
      }else if(value == ''){//checks emtpy rows in between statuses just in case there and logs the result
        Logger.log('Empty value on row '+x);
      }else{
        Logger.log('Existing timestamp on row '+x);//skips and logs all rows on column C with existing timestamps to ensure timestamps are not overridden
      }
  }
}
```

After running the script, `queued` was added with a timestamp on row 3 as seen on test Sheet below:

[image]

Lastly, here's the execution log:

[image]